# How to check build version greater than android N

Tags: android, android-build

`if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){...do something..}`

unable to find N.how to check build version  greater than android N

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36357030/3395198

Comment: if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {...do something..}

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya I want to check for greater than N

Comment: @BharatKumarEmani Re-open your question . Please check given link

Answer (score 5):

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
// perform Opertaion
}
```

This Must Work. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24){...do something..}

maybe this works

Answer (score 2):

```
Code name   Version     API level
Oreo        8.0         API level 26
Nougat      7.1         API level 25
Nougat      7.0         API level 24
```

You should check **`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N`**

> The “O” version is a provisional API level that is usable only for
>   development and testing during the Android O Developer Preview.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is I am using an **app (build.gradle)**  **build-tools version "23.0.3"** so I was unable to find N and I changed to **25.0.1** and it was working fine.

the minimum build tool version required for N is 24.

Comment: `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >25` ?

Comment: if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) this was working when i change my  buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"